# How do i access express.js routes from react.js client

Tags: reactjs, express

i'm trying to access express.js routes from react front end but i don't seem to get how to go about it. my express.js backend runs on localhost:9000 and my react frontend runs on localhost:3000. this is my react code;

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: "" };
}

callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/:username")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
}


render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{this.state.apiResponse}</p>

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

i have created two files on express routes folder, one is testAPI.js and the other is be.js. when i try to acces any of these two files from my browser without using react, on lets say localhost:9000/testAPI it works fine. but when i try to access localhost:3000/testAPI which calls the same file through react, it gives me this messed up error page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><h2>404</h2><pre>NotFoundError: Not Found at C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\app.js:33:8 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) at C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) at next (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) at C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15 at next (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14) at Function.handle (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3) at router (C:\Users\Denoh\full\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)</pre></body></html>
```

please assist

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `proxy` in package.json to achieve this

basically you set the url you  want to proxy too so that React knows how to connect to your server

see this for more info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/